# motor inertia tensor?

Tags: servomotor, dynamics

In modeling dynamics of a robot ,in which servo motor is adjusted inside the link, there is a need to find inertia tensor of the motor itself,Right?

[image]

So if it is needed how can i get the inertia tensor of motor since i couldn't find its solid works model having internal components,i mean gears and other stuff(with related specified materials)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to understand exactly what you are needing.   The motor specs should have a value for rotor inertia.   The gears would depend a lot on their design, but I have always been able to ignore their rotary inertias and just use the gear ratio in the overall drive train inertia calculations.   Those would be for the inertias distal to the motor.   For the inertias seen by the proximal motors, it is usually sufficient to model it as a point mass located at its cg.

Or, are you trying to inderstand *how* to create the inertia and mass matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't worry about modeling the dynamics.  You only need to do this in the case where you've got everything set up, but things aren't working as accurately as you'd like them to.  And in that case, the inertia that caused the overshoot should be visible in your data -- you can use the direct measurement instead of the theoretical calculation.

If you're asking about this because you're planning to push the servo to its physical limits, you should probably rethink your design.